# Not able to convert datefomat using Java

Tags: java, date

I have one date format in `2014-12-18T05:39:04.523Z`  I want to convert it into IST format.
I tried for this one.

```
 SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date date;
    try {
         //2014-12-04T12:27:15
        date = originalFormat.parse("2014-12-18T05:39:04.523Z");
        System.out.println("Old Format :   " + originalFormat.format(date));

        System.out.println("New Format :   " + targetFormat.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception *** " +ex);
    }
```

In output:

```
Old Format :   2014-12-18T05:39:04
New Format :   Thu Dec 18 05:39:04 IST 2014
```

Here instead of `z`, if I put `Z`, it is showing like this..

```
New Format :   Thu Dec 18 05:39:04 +0530 2014
```

But here I want to get 11:09 like this. How can I get the result I want?

Here day month date year all are perfect, but hours minutes seconds are not correct. I have to show 11 hours 09 minutes. Why? Because I am getting this date format one greenhouse Account. This belongs to US, so I want to convert into IST Format.

Comment: Yeah @Jens i have gone through this URL ..not getting according to my Requirement

Comment: @user3918280 could you explain what exactly didn't work according to your requirement? I guess you have to show that answers there don't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you parse the format, try small **hh**

When convert, try big **HH**

```
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

> In **Try-Catch**

```
targetFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
System.out.println(targetFormat.format(date));
```

p/s: Import the TimeZone first...

Comment: In Above code i have added Bigg HH Only..not working...Now i have edited code...itz show in format of +0530...But i want to show in 11 :19 minute.if i add 05:39:04 +0530.it is comming 11:09 minutes..Right

Comment: so how can i convert 05:39:04 +0530 into 11:09 minutes.

Comment: erm, see whether this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

try small ***hh*** in date format

```
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Comment: Yeah..@Prathap ..Same thing it is showing...